# Segmentation fault occurs when variable set to indexed parameter

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a poker game where an array of the players' hands and an array of the cards in the middle are passed as arguments to a function. In the function `get_winner`, I can loop over and print the cards in the arrays (2nd and 3rd for loops), but if I set a variable to an element of an array and print it, I get a segmentation fault. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

static const int num_players = 4;
static const char* SUITS[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
static const char* VALUES[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

enum suit {hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs};
enum value {two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};

struct card 
{
    value v;
    suit s;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const card &c)
{
    out << VALUES[c.v] << " of " << SUITS[c.s];
    return out;
}

int get_winner(const card (*hand)[num_players][2], const card (*commun_cards)[5])
{
    // this loop causes an error when printing the temp card variable  
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         auto temp_card = commun_cards[i];
         cout << *temp_card << " " << (*temp_card).s << " " << (*temp_card).v << endl;
    }
    // these loops work fine and print the players' hands and community cards
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        cout << (*hand)[i][0] << ", " << (*hand)[i][1] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << (*commun_cards)[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    card hands[num_players][2];
    card commun_cards[5];
    // fill hands and commun_cards with card structs
    hands[0][0] = card {jack, spades};
    hands[0][1] = card {nine, spades};
    hands[1][0] = card {ace, clubs};
    hands[1][1] = card {ace, hearts};
    hands[2][0] = card {three, diamonds};
    hands[2][1] = card {seven, spades};
    hands[3][0] = card {eight, diamonds};
    hands[3][1] = card {nine, clubs};
    commun_cards[0] = card {five, clubs};
    commun_cards[1] = card {king, hearts};
    commun_cards[2] = card {queen, spades};
    commun_cards[3] = card {two, spades};
    commun_cards[4] = card {ace, hearts};
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        cout << "Player " << i << " cards: " << hands[i][0] << ", " << hands[i][1] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nCommunity cards:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << commun_cards[i] << endl;
    }
    get_winner(&hands, &commun_cards);
}
```

Comment: Note: `(*temp_card).s` can be written `temp_card->s`.

Comment: You have created a struct to represent a card. Passing variables might be easier if you had a `hand` struct rather than passing an array of two cards.

Comment: Some tips : use [std::string](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-stdstring/) for strings, make a real struct for a card called Card (with members for suit and value). To have an array of cards , use std::vector<Card> and  std::vector<std::vector<Card>> for hands. The way you use arrays now is more like "C" did it then is recommended for C++ now.

Comment: If I have a vector of struct hand (two cards), should it be declared on the heap because the size will never change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function's 1st loop is accessing the `commun_cards` array incorrectly. Its 3rd loop is accessing the array correctly. Why would you expect the 1st loop to need to access the elements any differently than the 3rd loop just because it wants to save each element to a variable?

Since you are passing in each array by pointer, you must dereference each pointer *before* you can then index into the elements of each array. Your 2nd and 3rd loops are doing that. Your 1st loop is not.

Your 1st loop is expecting `commun_cards[i]` to yield a *pointer* to each element, but that is simply not true, which is why `*temp_card` then crashes. If you really want a pointer to each element, you need to use this instead:

```
auto *temp_card = &(*commun_cards)[i];
// alternatively:
// auto *temp_card = (*commun_cards) + i;
cout << *temp_card << " " << temp_card->s << " " << temp_card->v << endl;
```

Otherwise, use a reference to each element instead of a pointer:

```
auto &temp_card = (*commun_cards)[i];
// alternatively:
// auto &temp_card = *((*commun_cards) + i);
cout << temp_card << " " << temp_card.s << " " << temp_card.v << endl;
```

If you change the function to accept the arrays by reference instead of by pointer (which I highly suggest you do), then the function would become this:

```
int get_winner(const card (&hand)[num_players][2], const card (&commun_cards)[5])
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         auto &temp_card = commun_cards[i];
         cout << temp_card << " " << temp_card.s << " " << temp_card.v << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        cout << hand[i][0] << ", " << hand[i][1] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << commun_cards[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

...

get_winner(hands, commun_cards);
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop should be

```
// this loop causes an error when printing the temp card variable  
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     auto temp_card = (*commun_cards) + i; // change here
     cout << *temp_card << " "<< temp_card->s << " " << temp_card->v << endl;  // change here
}
```

`auto temp_card = &(*commun_cards)[i];` is another way of writing auto `temp_card = (*commun_cards) + i;` and `temp_card->s` is another way of writing `(*temp_card).s`.

But you've written code that is unnecessarily complex by passing pointers to your arrays instead of pointers to your array **elements**. The name of an array decays into a pointer to it's first element, so
`card commun_cards[5]` becomes `card *commun_cards` and `card hand[num_players][2]` becomes `card (*hand)[2]`. This is how you normally pass an array to a function.

Here's the whole function simplified

```
int get_winner(const card (*hand)[2], const card *commun_cards)
{
    // this loop causes an error when printing the temp card variable  
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        auto temp_card = commun_cards[i];
        cout << temp_card << " " << temp_card.s << " " << temp_card.v << endl;
    }
    // these loops work fine and print the players' hands and community cards
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        cout << hand[i][0] << ", " << hand[i][1] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << commun_cards[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then

```
int main()
{
    ...
    get_winner(hands, commun_cards);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the distinction of pointers to arrays vs pointers to array elements

Comment: Just one question: When passing commun_cards to the function, commun_cards is an array of cards, but in the function there is a * which means that the commun_cards is an array of pointers to cards? If that is the case, why can you use . instead of -> and if I iterate through every card in commun_cards, it seems like the card is not a pointer which confuses me

Comment: @kjdfsjdsakafsjna Which version of the function are you talking about? In my version `const card *commun_cards)` is a pointer to cards, in your version `const card (*commun_cards)[5]` its a pointer to an array of card. Neither version is an array of pointers to cards (that would be `const card *commun_cards[5]`).

Comment: @kjdfsjdsakafsjna The difference between `T (*x)[N]` and `T *x[N]` is that the first is a pointer to an array, and the second is an array of pointers.